# Jquery UI -sortable between one DIV to another Div, without sortable in within the DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

[image: Ref image]

I have 'N' number of start row  (red border) I want sortable(number box 1, 2, 3 etc..) form start row(red border) to receive row(green border).

sortable should not work within start row (red border). And sortable within the receive row (green border) must work.

**Here i want to only disable/ cancel sortable function within the start row(red border).**

i have used below script code.

```
     $('.draggable-row').sortable({
      connectWith:".sortable-row"

      });

     $('.sortable-row').sortable({
      connectWith:".sortable-row"
      });
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhil/2tn0903g/2/)

Comment: This is one of the [examples](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) on the jQuery UI site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the sortable row should be `.sortable`; the others should be `.draggable`.

```
$('.draggable-row span').draggable({
    connectToSortable:".sortable-row",
    revert: 'invalid'                  
});

$('.sortable-row').sortable({
    revert: true           
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2tn0903g/4/

Comment: How  to **add Class** to currently  **draggable item** (this item), this should work **after draggable** completed.